# clearInterval not clearing the set interval onMouseUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval, mousedown

Trying to make a button event onMouseDown, a function should run at the end of the set amount of time. The function runs onMouseDown and clears the interval onMouseUp, but the interval still runs after releasing the button.

This is the code currently. I have the interval global and set it in the planting function. It should unset in the notPlanting function, but it does not.

```
import React from "react";

function PlantDefuser() {
    var interval

    function planting() {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Defuser Planted")
        }, 1000)
    }

    function notPlanting() {
        console.log(interval)
        clearInterval(interval)
    }

    return (
        <button onMouseDown={planting} onMouseUp={notPlanting}>Press and Hold</button>
    )
}

export default PlantDefuser
```

Comment: Note that your mouse up function will only fire if you are hovering over the button, you might want to detect window level mouse up and clear your interval when that triggers instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could help you:

`useRef` allows us to store and update data in the component without triggering a re-render. Now the only re-render happens when the props are updated.

We can store interval in a `ref` like so

```
import { useRef } from "react";

const PlantDefuser = () => {
  const interval = useRef();

  function planting() {
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Defuser Planted");
    }, 1000);
  }

  function notPlanting() {
    clearInterval(interval.current);
  }

  return (
    <button onMouseDown={planting} onMouseUp={notPlanting}>
      Press and Hold
    </button>
  );
}

export default PlantDefuser
```

Comment: Hey this works! Thanks for the answers everyone. Seems like I still have a lot to learn about react.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare variables like so in the function component, it is being created on each render. You should be saving the interval id in a state like so:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const PlantDefuser = () => {
    const [plantingInterval, setPlantingInterval] = useState(null);

    const planting = () => {
        const plantingIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Defuser Planted");
        }, 1000);
        setPlantingInterval(plantingIntervalId);
    };

    const notPlanting = () => {
        clearInterval(plantingInterval);
        setPlantingInterval(null);
    };

    return (
        <button onMouseDown={planting} onMouseUp={notPlanting}>
            Press and Hold
        </button>
    );
};

export default PlantDefuser;
```

You might also want to make sure the interval is being cleared when the component unmounts.

Comment: Setting the `interval` in state it doing an unnecessary re-render. best options here it using the `useRef` hook

Comment: You are right, but it doesn't matter in the slightest. You know how we handle for example values of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **useEffect hook** with `cleanup function`   to manage the `clearInterval` method .

**like this :**

```
function PlantDefuser() {
  const [run, setRun] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (run) {
      const countTimer = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("Defuser Planted");
      }, 1000);

      return () => {
        console.log(countTimer);
        clearInterval(countTimer);
      };
    }
  }, [run]);

  return (
    <button onMouseDown={() => setRun(!run)} onMouseUp={() => setRun(!run)}>
      Press and Hold
    </button>
  );
}

export default PlantDefuser;
```